# Is it correct to choose a model based on variable type or variable distribution?

Tags: distributions, density-function, discrete-data

I have a dependent variable that is Poisson distributed, but it is not 'count' data or data collected over a given time period.  It is discreet and positive, with values from 1-10, and it is heavily left-skewed, with a mean of about 1.7.

The variable is from a survey question with 10 possible answers, basically an ordinal scale variable.  Can I use Poisson or negative-binomial regression for this even though the variable is not a traditional 'count' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest this is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) problem with $n=10$. The probability mass function is
$$Pr(k;n,p) = \Pr(X = k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\;.$$
Here is a comparison of synthetic binomial mass data from 100 samples with a probability, $p$, of 0.17, for $n=10$ questions and the binomial mass function itself in percentage. The x-axis shows $k$, the number of successes in $n=10$ trials. The mean is $np=10\times0.17=1.7$.

[image]

The binomial mass is in light red, the simulated data is in light blue, and the overlap is purple colored.